# iOS cordova set DisallowOverscroll to true not only on the main screen of the app

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, bounce

I have a Cordova (version 6.3.1) app. This issue only occurs on iOS version of the app (Android works fine). Every time i press on a text box to insert a text after doing some scrolling, it jumps straight back to the top. After some investigating, I found out that

```
DisallowOverscroll=true
```

in cordovas "config.xml" only works on the main screen of the app, not if I go and click on a "modal" "KompressionStromper" in the video (it does not work inside there), so how can I enable it inside there? So the behaviour is not like in video?

Please [see video here](https://youtu.be/StzENf6PgW0)  on iOS 10.0.2 (during the first seconds i also try to pull at the main screen from top to bottom but there the "DisallowOverscroll" option works as expected).

Any other suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific element you can disable overscroll with jQuery.

Like:

```
element.ontouchmove = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I strongly suggest that you also create a directive out of it, so it will be more done in a "angular way".